# Which statistical test to use for non-square contingency tables

Tags: r, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, contingency-tables

I have data before treatment encoded with numbers 1 or 2 which are two different types of a disease. The data after treatment are encoded  with numbers 0,1 or 2 where 0 means that the patient has fully recovered. 2 is a more serious form of disease compare to 1.

I want to check whether the treatment is effective or not. I cannot run MacNemar's test given that the contigency table is not square. I cannot either perform chi-square test because the data before and after treatment are not independent.

Can someone please recoment what kind of test can I perform?

Comment: But did all of your patients get treated? In that case you cannot distinguish between the treatment effect and natural recovery. Don't you have a control group that did not get treated?

Comment: If you just want to test association between disease type and recovery, you can use Chi-square or Fisher's exact test.

Comment: Yes all the patients get treated. No, I don't have a group that did not get treated. I want to test association between before and after treatment basically

Answer (score 1):

Then **Chi-square** or **Fisher's exact test** are what you need. They test if the disease status before and after are independent. Rejecting the null hypothesis indicates that there does exist an association between the before and after status.

Comment: OK, let me clarify one more thing. If you reject the null hypothesis and there is an association between the before and after status. Can you conclude if the treatment is useful or not? Because this is the overall aim. To check whether the treatment is useful or not.

Comment: Since you only have data of patients that get treated, you cannot conclude this from your data. You would need a control group of patients that did not get treated, and then test for a difference between the two groups.